# NSObject as delegate for UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsobject

I have a `UITableView` which is dragged into a `UIViewController` and a `NSObject` class. This `NSObject` class should serve as delegate and datasource to the tableview.

I tried creating an instance of NSObject and conformed delegate and datasource to the tableview. Datasource is working fine. But the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is never getting called and all i get is a `EXC_BAD ACCESS` and app just stops right there. But when I drag a object to `UIViewController` bottom pane and giving the class name to it and setting delegate and datasource, everything is working good and `UITableView` is displaying.

I don't know why this strange behaviour.
I have done this in the viewdidload of viewcontroller class.

```
customnsobject *custom=[customnsobject alloc]init];
tableview.delegate=custom;
tableview.datasource=custom;
```

Comment: You will need to show some code as it's difficult to help/understand without seeing.

Comment: Most possibly you have the local instance of `NSObject` subclass which is being released. Show the code from viewController where you are creating the DataSource.

Comment: If you do not hold a reference to `custom` in this case then at the end of the method here it shall be deallocated since both he `delegate` and the `datasource` only hold weak references.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Ok delegate and datasource are deallocated because custom is holding weak references. So how to stop them from deallocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a parent id in your class h file like this
    @property(nonatomic,retain) id parent;
and in your view controller just below the instance of nsobject you created do this
    custom.parent=self;
I hope this will work